# PHP function - Ordering of readdir file listing is odd

Tags: php, readdir, opendir

I have some PHP script that reads an image directory and echos out the results of the users search.

I need to find a way of sorting these search results from the directory, I know you can use natsort() on an array but this does not help as the results are not in an array, just a while statement.

Does anyone know if this is doable? Or maybe it would be easier to adapt my code to add the file names to an array first?

```
  <?php
    $dir = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Library", true);
    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if(stristr($file,$_POST['image_search'])){
                    echo ('<li><div class="thumb-contain"><a href="/'.$dir . $file.'" class="photo-link" rel="attachment"><img src="/asset-thumbs/'. $file .'" /></a><br/><p><a href="/'.$dir . $file.'" class="photo-link" target="_blank">View image</a> | <a href="/download.php?download_file='.$dir . $file.'">Download image</a> <p>'. $file .'</p></div></li>');
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
  ?>
```

Ok I got it working by adding results into an array - I am not a PHP wizard so if anyone spots anything that could be cleaner that would be fantastic, otherwise thanks for your help.

```
<?php
$dir = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Library", true);
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(stristr($file,$_POST['image_search'])){
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        natsort($files);
            foreach($files as $file) {
                echo ('<li><div class="thumb-contain"><a href="/'.$dir . $file.'" class="photo-link" rel="attachment"><img src="/asset-thumbs/'. $file .'" /></a><br/><p><a href="/'.$dir . $file.'" class="photo-link" target="_blank">View image</a> | <a href="/download.php?download_file='.$dir . $file.'">Download image</a> <p>'. $file .'</p></div></li>');
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not iterate over the `readdir` result and add the items to an array. Then sort that array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] )` - it returns array and support sorting as option.